# GNU make - reference targets in another makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

**Preface:**

Yes, my makefiles are written badly.
No, I/we didn't write them; we inherited this code base from another company.
I want to know if it's possible to fix my problem WITHOUT rewriting them.

**Question**

Is there a way to reference targets from another makefile and use those as prerequisites?

Say you have:

```
all: libs binary

binary: # I need to add prereqs here
    blah
    blah2
    blah3
```

For `binary`, I need to targets in other makefiles as prereqs.
I cannot just `include` those makefiles, and therefore those targets, because those makefiles define identical variables but with different values.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
binary: C:/mk1:foo C:/mk2:bar
    blah
    blah2
    blah3
```

**UPDATE**

In case it's not clear, makefiles`C:/mk1` and `C:/mk2`are part of the same makefile project that is being executed via some top level makefile with `make --jobs=X` so in theory all makefiles could be being made in parallel.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: yes, but you may wind up rebuilding targets unnecessarily. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @Beta yes. Primary objective is minimal modification of makefiles so obviously there'll be compromise. Please proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **Recursive Make** [duhn-duhn-*duhnnnn!*] is the right tool for the job:

```
binary: foo bar
    blah
    blah2
    blah3

.PHONY: foo bar

foo:
    $(MAKE) -f mk1 $@

bar:
    $(MAKE) -f mk2 $@
```

The `PHONY` forces Make to execute those rules and invoke the other makefiles to (perhaps) rebuild `foo` and `bar` even if they already exist (because this makefile doesn't know what prerequisites they may have).

Comment: What about race conditions: what happens if `foo`'s recipe in this makefile is executed while simultaneously another `make` in parallel is `make`-ing `foo` in file `mk1`?

Comment: @Adrian: It isn't wise to attempt to parallelize recursive Make.

Comment: I don't follow. You mean don't use `--jobs`?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [`include makefile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) (or `sinclude`) mechanism to incorporate the inherited makefile? This should work as long as your own targets have different names.

You can also concatenate makefiles by specifying multiple `-f makefile` options. They are concatenated in order.

Comment: But I have about 40 makefiles that have the same variables but different values for them so when I `include` them I'll have: "variable declarations" \n "targets" \n "same variables redecorated" \n "possibly targets with same name as above"

Comment: Won't the later variable redeclarations override the earlier ones? And I'll get outright errors because many of these makefiles have same target names like `all`

Comment: @Adrian Well, with the same variables, obviously the original make process couldn't have been invoked simultaneously or in parallel to create everything in one go. Then you shouldn't attempt it either. Since you don't want to rewrite them, you'll have to use them as they were designed. Maybe you could write a script and make calling that script a command in a recipe? This may not be perfect from a minimalist point of view, but might be much easier than sophisticated make hackery.

Comment: there's a misunderstanding. If the variables and target names are in separate files it doesn't matter if the variables and target names are the same.

Comment: but if you include them all in into the same makefile then you have a problem